# Do SQLite STRICT tables make any performance or operational difference?

Tags: sqlite

SQLite recently added optional STRICT tables, which enforce column types. Obviously, the question of whether enforced types are an aid to correctness, could be debated at length, and has been, in many places; I'm not asking about that here. I'm asking a different question:

Do strict tables make any other difference?

For example, one could imagine they might be slightly slower (CPU cycles spent doing type checks), or slightly faster and more compact (table data doesn't need to provide for multiple possible types). Or maybe there might be some other difference I haven't thought of.

Do they make any difference, apart from the actual type checking?